# pass a file name as a job parameter while executing a spring batch job with json api

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Please how do i pass a file name as a job parameter while executing a spring batch  job with json api?

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("jobparameters", "filename="  + UPLOAD_LOCATION + uploadedFile.getFileName() + ".csv");

            RestTemplate rstTpl = new RestTemplate();

            String result = rstTpl.postForObject(url, map, String.class);
```

And access the file from my job e.g

```
<bean id="edivJobFile" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource"
    scope="step">
    <constructor-arg value="#{jobParameters[filename]}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you please explain and show code for the part where the json api receives parameters and starts a job?

Answer (score 1):

I later discovered that spring batch JSON api for POST(that launches a job) allows job parameters to be passed as POST request parameter (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/reference/json.html) e.g
jobparameters=filename=myfile.csv, batchCode=001

jobparameters=filename=myfile.csv, batchCode=001

So I later did:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> mvm = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();

String fileNameParam = "filename="  +  UPLOAD_LOCATION + "/" + uploadedFile.getFileName();

String batchCodeParaam = "batchCode=" + uploadedFile.getBatchCode();
String companyCodeParam =  "companyCode=" + companyCode;


mvm.add("jobParameters", fileNameParam + "," + batchCodeParaam + "," + companyCodeParam);

RestTemplate rstTpl = new RestTemplate();

String result = rstTpl.postForObject(url, mvm, String.class);
```

And it worked. 
@Michael Pralow, the spring api is exposed by spring batch admin as as option for monitoring and launching jobs. 
Thanks